# Can you commit without Global Email and Username in Git in Windows 11?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a repo which is set up using SSH connection. I have tested the SSH connection, and it shows my GitHub username is connected and recognized. But when I commit it asks me for my username and email? I can add my email and username globally in git, but I was wondering whether I commit without that.

I am using Windows 11. My git version is 2.41.0.windows.1.

I have run all the steps of:

- creating new ssh key
- evaluating the key
- adding the key
- copying and pasting in GitHub Keys
- starting and testing the connection
  everything works fine.

Comment: committing != pushing/fetching. A GitHub account is required to push to GitHub. Username and email are stored with each commit as the author (and committer) information.

Comment: If you want to keep your email private, you can use the **private email** feature: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github

Comment: And optionally configure your github account to not expose your private email address: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/blocking-command-line-pushes-that-expose-your-personal-email-address